# How to use wild cards in FT search

Tags: lotus, xpages, lotus-domino

I have the following:

```
tmpArray[cTerms++] = "[sclenka] CONTAINS \"*" + sessionScope.sclenka +"*\"";
```

(With the help of [Per Henrik Lausten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785061/per-henrik-lausten))

Which should result in: `"*term*"`
But it doesn't, I get this instead: `"term"`

So, my question is how do I use wildcard full text search?

Thank you!

Comment: With proper formating of the question, it should read 

... Which should result in: `"*term*"`
But it doesn't, I get this instead: `"term"` ...

Comment: As I understood your issue in the chat, the "[field] CONTAINS query" only works if the query has 5 or more characters. You are therefore looking for the correct syntax to be able to combine a field specific search with a wild card search

Comment: Is this a typeahead search? FTI search should work with 3 characters or more. Also you shouldn't need to wrap it in quotes unless you are adding further conditions to the search.

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten, I managed to add the stars the way you showed me... But I get no results.
A colleague of mine suggested that it might be some settings that need to be adjusted. But I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a wildcard search, then generate the following query string:

```
tmpArray[cTerms++] = "[sclenka] = \"*" + sessionScope.sclenka +"*\"";
```

This should generate a search on `"*search query*"`.

In general, this is a good way of performing a search since the user probably expect your search to work like that.

Source: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Searching_for_Documents#Full-text+Search

Comment: I'm sorry to post this late. This actually gave the right results! Thank you to everyone who tried to help me, I'm sure this will help someone else too. @Per [here](goo.gl/ZPdhX) it says that ( CONTAINS/contains/= ) don't work on the web. But maybe it's old so they got it to work :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If your string is correct and you are getting no results, then test the same string in the Notes client FTI search.

You can also use the following debug on the server.

```
DEBUG_FTV_SEARCH=1
```

Then check the output on the domino console when you do a search.

Comment: I get perfect results when using the Notes Client FT search. About the Debug, i will try it on Monday when I get to work. I will post the results. Thank you

Comment: Please notice my answer about using = instead of CONTAINS. I believe this is the cause of the search getting no results. Looking forward to hear about your results on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed a bit of escaping characters in the String you are generating.

tmpArray[cTerms++] = "[sclenka] CONTAINS *\"" + sessionScope.sclenka +"*\"";

Comment: you should add some sort of explaination to the line of code you provided, while it may answer the question it is a very low quality reply.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you, the result is an escaped form of the search term in which the asterisks have been removed?

Could you use the construct:

tmpArray[cTerms++]  = "[sclenka] CONTAINS \"" + String.fromCharCode(42) + sessionScope.sclenka + String.fromCharCode(42) + "\"";

At least that should avoid escaping?

Comment: Dec, remember when you suggested I'd get better results if I posted some code?   I think, if you could, it might help to see the next bit -- the code that does the ftsearch.

Answer (score 0):

leyrer, is it possible -- just possible -- that you're doing this in a browser and your session is not authenticated?  If so, you may be searching the database as "anonymous" where when you test from the browser you're searching as "leyrer".

It's just a thought - but I used to see that all the time when people would start using my NCT Search tools.   They'd swear they were getting no results, and when I'd dig I'd always find that they were using the browser as anonymous rather than as a logged in session.

Comment: I'll answer on behalf of gkidd (who asked the question. Leyrer only edited it). He is getting results but only for exact search terms - not for wildcard searches.

Comment: have him try this alternative syntax ...Instead of "contains" just use "=" I don't recall if the asterisk wildcard works with contains.

Comment: Thank you Per. Andrew, I'm getting the results with Anonymous user, but not with the wildcard.
Here http://goo.gl/YVtXm on the first line, it says that CONTAINS or contains or = does not work when searching from the web.

Comment: Ok, try this:   Create another agent that does JUST the search.  Have it grab the search term from agent context as if it were a docid.  Call the agent from the first agent using  "agent.runonserver(searchterm)"   see if you can fool it.

Answer (score 0):

@GKIDD

I just tested this on my own site.  I have NCTSearch setup.   I accepts the search term from the the web and runs database.ftsearch() as part of its job from within lotuscript.

I searched on "data*" and got at least as many results as when I searched on "database".

Based on that, I think something else is going on.

From my earlier comment on other answer, try this: Create another agent that does JUST the search. Have it grab the search term from agent context as if it were a docid. Call the agent from the first agent using "agent.runonserver(searchterm)" see if you can fool it

> Andrew, I'm getting the results with Anonymous user, but not with the wildcard. Here goo.gl/YVtXm on the first line, it says that CONTAINS or contains or = does not work when searching from the web.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see what i'll come up with.